# .all() on pandas series not return expected behavior

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a dataframe called `df_output` like so

```
index  col1
0    | ''
1    | ''
2    | ''
3    | ''
4    | ''
```

If I run `df_output['col1'].values.all() == ''` my return value is `true`. However if I edit the dataframe so it looks like this

```
index  col1
0    | '324'
1    | ''
2    | ''
3    | ''
4    | ''
```

And run `df_output['col1'].values.all() == ''` I still get a return value of `true`. Shouldn't this line return false, since the value at index 0 for col1 is '324'? Or am I misunderstanding how .all() works on a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df_output['col1'] == '324'` will give you a **per-row** comparison with `'342'` resulting in a Series of True/False. Then you **reduce** those True/False into one with `(df_output['col1'] == '324').all()` which will be False for both of your example dataframes. However, `(df_output['col1'] == '').all()` should give you a True for your first dataframe.